# Can't bind React element to event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

I have this code (edited down to the relevant part):

main.js

```
import { mouseDownEvent } from '../common';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.btn.addEventListener(
      'mousedown',
      mouseDownEvent.bind(this) // <-- not working!
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="btn" className="btn"/>
    );
  }
}
```

common.js:

```
export const mouseDownEvent = event => {
  console.log(this); // <-- 'undefined'
}
```

However, `this` inside of `mouseDownEvent` in `common.js` is `undefined`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using an arrow function:

```
export const mouseDownEvent = event => {
  console.log(this); // <-- 'undefined'
};
```

This causes `mouseDownEvent` to not get its own dynamic `this`; it uses the `this` from the lexical outer scope. You should instead use `function`:

```
export function mouseDownEvent (event) {
    console.log(this);
}
```